# What means the gdal_translate message: "Too many command options"?

Tags: gdal, postgresql, error

I have a little question, regarding the gdal_translate-utility:

I want to extract raster-files from database-stored gridfiles using the gdal_translate:

> gdal_translate -ot Float32 -of SAGA PG: "host='localhost' port='5432' dbname='$dbname' user='$dbowner' schema='grids' table='testrun' mode='2'" /output/...

But instead of delivering output it shows me "Too many command options." Then it lists usage and supported output formats. What does this message mean? I was searching the net already but found nothing which could be helpful.

Thanks for an answer in advance,
knutella

Comment: It probably means that you haven't specified the command args in a valid way.  You have either supplied incorrect args or the formatting has caused gdal to parse it in a way that is not expected.

Comment: Thanks David, for your quick reply. It seems that connection-arguments are committed properly through the script/me. About the input format from database I'm not sure now, because there is complex function behind. I guess I must dive a bit deeper into the dbase. Thanks David.

Comment: UPDATE: It was indeed my fault:  I forgot to put the mode=2 into inverted comma... %)  In question-post its corrected already.